# Сhanging the camera path

Tags: animation, camera, bezier-curves, path

I need to change the camera path at key points. When moving the curve vertices after empty, the camera stays exactly where I want it. But when editing vertices in front of empty, the camera changes its position
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this solution: Create a cube (or a triangle), select the camera, shift select the cube, switch to *Edit* mode, select 3 vertices, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Make Vertex Parent*:

[image]

Give your cube a *Curve* modifier with the curve as *Curve Object*:

[image]

Now when you increase or reduce the length of the curve the camera doesn't move:

[image]

Comment: Très bien! but... if I change the position of the first vertex of the curve, then the camera will change its position

Comment: oops yes you're right