# It is possible to change part of path and don't changing other, when animating camera with the path?

Tags: camera, path

when I use constraint > Follow Path on curve with camera, animate it and change a part of path, all animation is screwing up :/ (like at the video) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RbjLDqhLO_c

It is possible to change part from C to B and not affected with part A to C? I know it it possible to make a few pathes and change camera constraints with influence option, but this is not flexible and hard to have smooth movement.

[Blend. file with this scene to download](https://mab.to/20KqClNPm)

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/258190/2214

Comment: vklidu thanks for answer, that will be helpful, but it is possible to edit A to C and don't affected C to B ect. ? I mean to separate path at few peaces with animation, and make edits only at specific part?

Comment: You can Split Curve, but animation wouldn't continue. It stops at the end of the first segment. If you just need to change curvature of BC segment without affecting curvature of AC, that just change handle type (V) to Free for C control point. The link in my first post let you result animation independent on anim curve length.